# Properly joining a key-value table to a master table

Tags: mysql

We have a primary table and a secondary table to hold a bunch of key-value pairs that are associated with the main table. The reasoning behind this is that as our data grows, so will the number of different types of 'keys'. Current structure:

```
Main Table:
id|name

Secondary Table:
id|key|value
```

I would like to select all records from the main table, and select a few keys from the secondary table. The way I am doing it now is:

```
SELECT main_table.id, main_table.name, s1.value, s2.value
FROM main_table
LEFT JOIN secondary_table s1 ON s1.id = main_table.id AND s1.key = 'cats'
LEFT JOIN secondary_table s2 ON s2.id = main_table.id AND s2.key = 'dogs'
```

I have to use LEFT JOIN as some records will not have a corresponding record in the second table, but I need the record to return anyway. This seems inefficient to me and quite slow. Perhaps I am going about it the wrong way? How can I improve the structure/query?

Comment: Why do you think left join is inefficient? How did you measure efficiency?

Comment: Do you have a FK constraint defined to enforce indexing? Do you have an index on `key`?

Comment: Alex, I ment that the whole query seems inefficient. We are currently  joining 6 different keys per query. I have it my head that joining the same table 6 times seems "inefficient".

Comment: Doe you really need to have the multiple key values returned within the same result row?  This seems really non-scalable if you want to look up values for any number of keys.

Comment: There is an index on key|id and id|key.

Comment: Mike, it is up to the user to have as many keys as they choose so. It was a choice to go with key pairs instead of having to alter the table structure and add a new column every time we grow the data set. If we want to pull keys for one record, its simple enough. But in a lot of cases, we want to return 1000 rows from main_table with 2-3 keys from the secondary table for each row.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you should abandon your approach of trying to return all you query data in one record and just query the relational database the way it is meant to be queried.  So do something like this":

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, s.key, s.value
FROM main_table AS m
INNER JOIN secondary_table AS s ON m.id = s.id
WHERE key IN ('cats', 'dogs', 'tigers', 'elephants')
```

I am imaging in this case you have a primary key on `m.id` and a compound primary key on `s.id, s.key`.  You would also need a separate index on `s.key` to optimize this query.

This would return multiple rows in the result set.

Comment: What if I have 100 keys per id? Wouldn't that mean I would have to loop through 100 keys at a time to get a complete row back? What if one of the keys is missing? Just trying to better understand this approach

Comment: @PaulS. No, it would mean that you would have 100 rows.  I think perhaps you are hung up on the concept all getting all your data back in one row.  That is not really how relational databases are designed to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT   main_table.id, main_table.name,
         MAX(IF(s.key='cats',s.value,NULL)),
         MAX(IF(s.key='dogs',s.value,NULL))
FROM     main_table LEFT JOIN secondary_table s USING (id)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Egg, will give this approach a shot since it looks like I wouldn't need to change the code all that much, thank you very much.

Comment: Egg, the queries are taking 2-3x longer than my original approach. Any ideas why?